# jquery  unexpected end of input in browser console (Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: jquery, console, syntax-error

First of all this the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/EQLhu/) 
I'm trying to add this script on my actual website header which is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#header").hide();
    jQuery("a#toggle").click(function() {
        jQuery("#header").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").find(".close").on("click", function() {
            jQuery(this).parents("#header").fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
});​
</script>
```

If I test it in jsfiddle everything works fine, but when I implement it on my website I get this in Chrome console:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL** 
What is wrong?

This is the [website.](http://whiteandgold.ro/ipp/)

Comment: It's kind of spaghetti code... One more thing, when you say it doesn't work in Chrome, it sounds like it works somewhere else. Mentioning other browsers could help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug says that your newlines are bad:

[image: firebug]

So, my guess is that you're uploading in the wrong FTP format or similar. Check your editor or IDE's settings and try once more.

You can also use `dos2unix` via an SSH connection to try to normalize your line endings to unix ones if you have shell access.